# Can do I brutefore wifi password with handshake without wifi detection?

Tags: wifi, aircrack-ng, handshake

I have captured handshake but now I want to bruteforce wifi without detection it (in different place). Is it possible? If yes, how to do that?

Comment: Can you clarify what protocol (WEP, WPA, WPA2) and what specifically you are trying to brute force?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have written that you captured the handshake.The next logical step is to bruteforce the cap file that you obtained at the handshake part.For that use the following command 
aircrack-ng capfile -w wordlistfile

ofcourse change the capfile to the name of your cap file and your own wordlist

P.s:- You should really google first before asking